# Ubuntu 22.04 Chrome cannot rename filename when saving images

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, rename

Ubuntu 22.04
using Chrome, I select an image, R-click, Save As Image
The dialog pops up with the suggested image name

Previously, I had already copied some text to use as the new image name, however, I cannot paste it into the dialog  above.  Instead the dialog gives a list of suggested names from a history somewhere.

How can I revert back to the old method of pasting copied text as the  filename?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 using Chrome, the same for PDFs. Cant paste anything, it says "The folder contents could not be displayed".

Comment: I have this problem as well. I use Ubuntu MATE 22.04 and when Right clicking on an image in Chrome and choose Save As, It starts searching, rather than letting me rename the file. Happens in Firefox as well, always defaults to search when trying to change the Save As name.Would have saved this as a comment but I don't have 50 reputation

Comment: The same problem occurs on Brave browser.  It is not possible to set the name of a downloaded file.

Comment: By Chrome, do you mean the [Chromium snap](https://snapcraft.io/chromium)?

Comment: please tell us which chrome you are using, version, how did you install it. `realpath $(which google-chrome)`, `realpath $(which chromium)`

Comment: A screenshot of what the "save as" dialog looks like would help

Comment: Looks like a "snap" problem. Using Chrome from .deb file doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I found this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4798 it seems to appear on debian flavors with non-Gnome desktops...

Comment: I had the problem on a system with snapd v 2.58, installed by apt. But not on a system with snapd v 2.58.3, installed by snap, itself. Doing this on the bad system fixed the problem with Chromium and Firefox: sudo snap install snapd

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as Brian and cannot comment.

How are you trying to paste, via the right-click context menu or by keyboard shortcut i.e. Ctrl+V

I am currently testing out 22.04 on an old PC and installed Chrome via terminal using: `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and then `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Unlike you I can right-click, Save Image As... and paste with mouse a custom name I have in my clipboard just fine.  So I wonder if your issue is something else.  What is your current desktop environment and desktop manager?  I ask because I changed mine and am wondering if this is the reason it works for me and not you.  I am using Cinnamon.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1270843)